# How can I use SCM changelist number as my artifact version in maven 3?

Tags: maven

In maven 2 I used a property for the artifact version and specified that on the command line using -D

i.e.

```
<artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
<version>${artifact.version}</version>

mvn clean install -Dartifact.version=SCM_Version
```

Maven 3 gives a warning on this:

> 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.

What is the proper way to do something like this in maven 3?

Comment: The usage in such a way does not make sense, every time i would call maven i have to define this property? Not very convienient...Just put in the version into and use the release plugin to release artifacts etc.

Comment: The property is defined by Jenkins our continuous integration and deployment server. Could we get the release plugin to pull or accept a property from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a useful answer, but this is an [open issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4715) in maven 3.